# Webpack 4 dev server exclude path

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-4

So I’m running a react app with webpack 4 dev server. I have a silent-renew.html file in the same folder as my index.html. I need to be able to go to localhost:8080/silen-renew and it needs to open the HTML file. But rigt now it spins up the spa with index.html every time i go to /sometimg. I can not use proxy as it is used for /API. And looks like proxy han not handle more then one path.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using htaccess file to set index file like the following snippet:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$

RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/silen-renew.html [L,R=301]
```